# How can I edit the string "Send this user a private message" in Privatemsg

Tags: privatemsg

Is it possible in the Privatemsg module (7.x-1.3) to edit the string "Send this user a private message" to something else without directly editing the modules code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> Features:
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.